# Continuous function between $[0,2\pi]$ and $S^{1}$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces

Here is the function between $[0,2\pi]$ and $S^1$ : for all $x\in [0, 2\pi]$ $f(x)=(\cos x,\sin x)$ . I know of that both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ is continuous that is why $f$ is continuous, but is there a solution to show $f$ is continuous with $\varepsilon,\delta$ technic?

I tried it a bit and I could not find and appropriate $\delta$ , I could not leave $\varepsilon$ alone. so  any hint will be appreciated, thanks much in advance.

Comment: $f$ is not a homeomorphism because $f(0)=f(2\pi)$.

Comment: Also it cannot be a homeomorphism since removing a point from the interval (not endpoint) leaves a disconnected set but removing any point from the circle leaves a connected set.

Comment: yes you are rihgt It was wrong one, just realised that. But is there anything that we you  say something about the $\varepsilon, \delta$ ? @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: You are extremely right, I have just edited it. @Anon

Comment: $\delta=\epsilon$ works.

Comment: thank you so much, but a bit computing needed I guess, analyses though @KaviRamaMurthy

Comment: Well, how are $\cos(x)$ and $\sin(x)$ defined for you? That's the crucial point. Most common definitions imply continuity quite easily. And differentiable $\to$ continuous is also elementary.

Comment: $cos: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow [-1,1]$ is defined, and I know that is easily continuous, actually did you mean what I wrote above by "defined"? @HennoBrandsma

Comment: It's trivial that when $x \to \cos(x)$ and $x \to \sin(x)$ are continuous, then so is $f$, and this *can* be shown by epsilon-delta techniques. But the tricky bit is to know that $x \to \cos(x)$ is continuous, the proof of which will depend on your *definition* of $\cos(x)$.

Comment: thank you so much sir, I will think on it.@HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $x$ and $y$ in $\mathbb{R}$.
\begin{align}
\left\|\left(\cos x,\sin x\right) - \left(\cos y, \sin y \right)
\right\| &= \left\|\left(\cos x - \cos y,\sin x - \sin y\right) \right\|\\
&= \sqrt{(\cos x - \cos y)^2 + (\sin x - \sin y)^2} \\
&\leqslant \sqrt{|x-y|^2 + |x-y|^2} ~~~~~~~ \big( \cos \text{ and } \sin \text{ are 1-Lipschitz}\big) \\
& \leqslant \sqrt{2}|x-y|.
\end{align}
It follows that your function is $\sqrt{2}$-Lipschitz, hence continuous.
If you really want an $(\varepsilon,\delta)$-proof, then choose $\delta = \frac{\varepsilon}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: How do you *know* that $\cos$ and $\sin$ are 1-Lipschitz, from first principles? (so no analysis allowed?)

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I agree that this seems non-trivial. But this is just a long story, not a difficult one, isn't it?

Comment: I was merely making the point that a full proof must take into account what the OP already knows and is allowed to asssume or not. If all first year analysis is allowed to be used, this question is not so hard. Otherwise it will depend on  definitions chosen, etc.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I totally agree with you. But the question wasn't "How to prove $\cos$ is $1$-Lipschitz from first principles", which deserves in itself a post on MSE.